# Is there any way to find the time taken by a function in the critical section(between disabling and enabling the interrupts)

Tags: c, interrupt, interrupt-handling, critical-section, powerpc

I have a function which will disable the interrupts before executing function and re enable interrupts after function is completed.

Here my requirement is to find **how much time taken by the function to be executed?**

In an abstract way this is what I want to do:

```
variable = time();//time before disabling

disable_interrupts();

perform_function();//business logic

enable_interrupts();

variable2 =time();//time after disabling the interrupt

tot_time = variable2 - variable;
```

Is there any way to find the time taken? I am stuck because if we disable interrupts the processor won't entertain anything(clock,interrupts,counters).

Comment: The clocks should continue to tick, even when interrupts are disabled?! The clock overruns will not be catched, as these are handled in interrupts as well. I hope, that your "//business logic" does not take too much time. As disabling the interrupts can have unwanted effect on many parts of your system.

Comment: my intention is exactly like clock should continue to tick but when we disabling the interrupt is there any clock which will run..because i am suspecting that function is taking so much time.. could please help me

Answer (score 1):

If this function is taking so much time you should probably change your design. And do the time consuming business logic without disabling the interrupts.

Anyways, if you want to stick to your current design i try to suggest a solution.
Any clock register will continue to run, you can choose one and check its value at the start and at the end of your ISR. You will have no indication if the counter will have overrun multiple times. You can also periodically ( if your business logic is a loop) check the clock value and sum the passed time into a variable. So the clock overruns will be included in the calculation.